# how to initialize 26 characters inside a 6*5 two dimensional matrix without using and extra special characters

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, indexoutofboundsexception, character-arrays

``I am a newbie to Java.
All i want to do is to store A to Z inside a 2D array like this

A B C D E

F G H I J

K L M N O

P Q R S T

U V W X Y

Z

```
String alphabets = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
 char[] alpha = alphabets.toCharArray;
 int k=0;
 char[][] cipher = new char[6][5];
 for(int i= 0;i<6;i++)
     {
       for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
           {
             cipher[i][j] = alpha[k];
             k++;
            }
     }
```

But this throws an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception i want the array to fill in 26 and leave the rest of the characters to be nulls. Is it possible ??

Comment: Well maybe you should have the code check to see whether "k" is too big.

Comment: Stop when you get to the end of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a break to exit the loop after filling the last letter.

```
String alphabets = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
char[] alpha = alphabets.toCharArray();
char[][] cipher = new char[6][5];
outerLoop : for(int i=0 ; i<cipher.length ; i++) {
   for(int j=0 ; j<cipher[0].length ; j++) {
       int k = i*cipher[0].length + j;
       if (k >= alpha.length) break outerLoop;
       cipher[i][j] = alpha[k];
   }
}
```

You can also use an array that has not the same number of columns in each row (last row would have only one column).

Comment: thank you :) but pardon me can u explain me what int k = i*cipher[0].length + j; does? As i m a newbie i couldnt just understand your code that easily kindly excuse me for being awkward

Comment: @user2860954 : This is the formula relating the indexes (i,j) in a matrix to the vectorized matrix (an array) in the conventionnal way (concatenate rows starting with the top of the matrix). You might see that a couple of times !

Comment: @user2860954 : You are welcome, but ifLoop's solution is more elegant. Forget about the Java 8 version if you don't understand it, his single loop is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is trying to fill the whole grid (30 spaces). When it runs out of letters (26) you get an out of bounds exception.
Easiest thing to do I guess would be

```
cipher[i][j] = alpha[k];
k++;
if (k >= alpha.length) {
    break;
}
```

Comment: This will only exit the nested loop, you need to break the outer loop.

Comment: You would if you weren't already in the bottom row, so the outer loop finishes anyway.

Answer (score 1):

the size of the alpha array is 26 so the max index of alpha is 25. but your 2d array has total 30 elements. so in your for loop there will be iteration where k value is greater than 25.

Answer (score 1):

In **Java 8** you could use a Stream for this kind of operation to get a neat solution (a so called 'one liner'):

```
IntStream.range('A', 'Z' + 1).forEach(c -> cipher[(c - 'A') / chipher[0].length][(c - 'A') % cipher[0].length] = (char)c);
```

**Pre Java 8** your goal could be reached by a simple for-loop:

```
for (int i = 'A'; i < 'Z' + 1; i++) {
    cipher[(i - 'A') / cipher[0].length][(i - 'A') % cipher[0].length] = (char)i;
}
```

Comment: I think it should be `cipher[0].length` and not `cipher.length - 1`. In that case it is the same, but in the general case it is the rows' length (width) that prevails, as we can see in the formula `k = i*width + j`.

Comment: @Dici you are right, I didn't thought about that enough. Thanks, edited.